# Он хотел объяснений. Из всех(,) пришедших ему на ум(,) ему нравилось такое

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

> Эдвард задумался. Он хотел объяснений. Из всех(,) пришедших ему на ум(,) ему нравилось такое...

Нужны ли запятые в отмеченных местах? Розенталь пишет, что с подобными местоимениями запятые не ставятся, но в то же время есть исключение:

> Но если определительный оборот имеет характер пояснения или уточнения [см. § 22, п. 4], то он обособляется (выделяется запятыми): *Всё, **связанное с железной дорогой**, до сих пор овеяно для меня поэзией путешествий* (Пауст.) — определительное местоимение субстантивировано.

Если честно, не очень понимаю, почему в его примере запятые нужны. Не является ли мой случай исключением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Эдвард задумался. Он хотел объяснений. Из всех пришедших  на ум (объяснений) ему нравилось такое...***

Предложение **неполное** (подразумевается существительное ***объяснений***), ***всех*** в данном случае  — это  местоимение в роли определения, поэтому оно не обособляется (субстантивации здесь нет).

В предложении стилистическая неточность — повтор местоимения ***ему***, которое лучше  убрать.

Comment: Спасибо. То есть, когда местоимение относится к какому-то существительному (даже если оно лишь подразумевается), запятые не ставятся. Когда местоимение и есть существительное, запятые ставятся. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: В вашем примере этот вопрос решается однозначно. В других же случаях автор сам определяет наличие или отсутствие субстантивации для местоимения, тогда возможны варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Нужны запятые. Это уточняющий причастный оборот (уточняет слово `всех`).

Более того, там делаются явные паузы при чтении.

Answer (score 0):

Закономерности, выявленные при анализе примеров из книг:

Если логическое ударение падает на общее слово, то нужно отделить оборот:

`Однако не всех, пришедших на спектакль, интересовало действо на сцене.`

(здесь основным является слово `всех` - `не всех интересовало`)

`И он очень быстро и ловко собрал нас всех, пришедших ночью, в караван.`

(собрал не `пришедших ночью в караван`, а `всех в караван`)

В примере из вопроса смысловое ударение тоже падает на слово `всех`.

Если `всех пришедших` является цельной фразой, а логическое ударение падает на слово `пришедших`, то запятая не ставится:

`Надо признаться, что никто из всех пришедших на кастинг тренеров до конца не верил, что все-таки такой канал появится.`

(здесь основная фраза - не `никто из всех`, а `никто из пришедших`; и логическое ударение падает на слово `пришедших`)

`Непонятно для чего, но дежурный опросил всех пришедших за мной в отделение.`

(логическая фраза не `опросил всех`, а `опросил пришедших`)

То есть нужно анализировать связь между словами вокруг оборота. Также нужно определить, какое слово является главным. Если общее - оборот выделяется, если слово из оборота - выделять не нужно.